# How can I solve: ${\left [{x+1}\over2\right]}={x-1\over 3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions, integers

How should the following equation be solved?
$${\left [{x+1}\over2\right]}={x-1\over 3}$$ where $[a]$ is the [integer part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html) of the number.

Comment: is this a algebra question?

Comment: Yes it is an algebra question

Comment: But are you sure the exercise should be solved this way @hit?

Comment: By integer part of a number, do you mean the least integer function, even for a negative number?

Comment: When $\dfrac{x-1}{3}$ is an integer?

Comment: For example we hav the number 2,5 and its integer part is 2

Comment: Yes, but what is the integer part of -2.5?  -2 or -3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we know that $\displaystyle \frac{x-1}{3}$ is an integer.  So we can write $x = 3k + 1$ for some integer $k$.

Now substitute:

$$k+1+\left[\frac{k}{2}\right] =  \left[\frac{3k+2}{2}\right] = k$$

$$\left[\frac{k}{2}\right] = -1$$

So $k = -1$ or $k = -2$.  Thus, the solutions for $x$ are $\{ -2,-5 \}$.

Comment: Can you please explain me why have  you extracted $k+1$ from under $\left[{{3k+2}\over 2}\right]$ ?

Comment: $[x+n] = [x] + n$ if $n$ is an integer.  Here, $\displaystyle \left[ \frac{3k+2}{2} \right] = \left[ k+1+\frac{k}{2} \right] = k+1+\left[ \frac{k}{2} \right]$

Answer (score 0):

The use of the floor function may be confusing because "traditional" means don't work.

But for one thing, we know that the left hand side is an integer, hence so is the right hand side, i.e. $x$ is of the form $3k+1$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$.
And we have the estimates $y-1<[y]\le y$, hence
$$ \frac{3k+2}{2}-1<k\le \frac{3k+2}{2}.$$
From the left inequality, $k<0$, from the right inequality $k\ge -2$. So there are only few cases left to test: $x=-5$ and $x=-2$.